# Maintaining exact aspect ratio when scaling videos using ffmpeg

Tags: ffmpeg, scaling, video-encoding

I have a mkv video, which is a mix of multiple resolution recordings, e.g. I have the first few seconds of widescreen 16:9 (1024x576) resolution, and the rest of the video if 4:3 (768x576) resolution. I want to scale this video down 3 times, while copying all the other attributes (audio codec, subtitles etc.). I use `ffmpeg -i <input_mkv> -vf scale=iw/2:-1 -acodec copy <output_mp4>`. Also, VLC detects it's resolution as 720x576.

The problem is that after the scaling, the resolution constantly becomes 4:3 (360x288). How can I maintain the dynamic aspect ratio of the input video file i.e. the 16:9 parts to scale to 16:9, while the 4:3 parts scale to 4:3?

**update**

The player size actually changes, atleast in mplayer, when the resolution is switched. I figured out the main problem. It seems each frame is tagged with a Sample Aspect Ratio (SAR), so when the player plays it, it can find the display aspect ratio. This SAR value isn't getting copied over when encoding to MKV. When encoding to MPG, it does get copied over and I get an exact copy, with the player switching sizes, but not with MKV.

Output of `ffprobe -show_streams filename`:

```
ffprobe version 0.10.3 Copyright (c) 2007-2012 the FFmpeg developers
  built on May  9 2012 17:51:07 with gcc 4.7.0 20120505 (prerelease)
  configuration: --prefix=/usr --enable-libmp3lame --enable-libvorbis --enable-libxvid --enable-libx264 --enable-libvpx --enable-libtheora --enable-libgsm --enable-libspeex --enable-postproc --enable-shared --enable-x11grab --enable-libopencore_amrnb --enable-libopencore_amrwb --enable-libschroedinger --enable-libopenjpeg --enable-librtmp --enable-libpulse --enable-gpl --enable-version3 --enable-runtime-cpudetect --disable-debug --disable-static
  libavutil      51. 35.100 / 51. 35.100
  libavcodec     53. 61.100 / 53. 61.100
  libavformat    53. 32.100 / 53. 32.100
  libavdevice    53.  4.100 / 53.  4.100
  libavfilter     2. 61.100 /  2. 61.100
  libswscale      2.  1.100 /  2.  1.100
  libswresample   0.  6.100 /  0.  6.100
  libpostproc    52.  0.100 / 52.  0.100
Input #0, matroska,webm, from 'sample.mkv':
  Metadata:
    title           : Pan prstenu. Dve veze
  Duration: 00:00:29.80, start: 0.000000, bitrate: 3124 kb/s
    Stream #0:0(eng): Video: mpeg2video (Main), yuv420p, 720x576 [SAR 64:45 DAR 16:9], 15000 kb/s, 25 fps, 25 tbr, 1k tbn, 50 tbc (default)
    Stream #0:1(cze): Audio: mp2, 48000 Hz, stereo, s16, 128 kb/s (default)
[STREAM]
index=0
codec_name=mpeg2video
codec_long_name=MPEG-2 video
codec_type=video
codec_time_base=1/50
codec_tag_string=[0][0][0][0]
codec_tag=0x0000
width=720
height=576
has_b_frames=1
sample_aspect_ratio=64:45
display_aspect_ratio=16:9
pix_fmt=yuv420p
level=8
timecode=16:35:19:10
id=N/A
r_frame_rate=25/1
avg_frame_rate=25/1
time_base=1/1000
start_time=0.000000
duration=N/A
nb_frames=N/A
TAG:language=eng
[/STREAM]
[STREAM]
index=1
codec_name=mp2
codec_long_name=MP2 (MPEG audio layer 2)
codec_type=audio
codec_time_base=1/48000
codec_tag_string=[0][0][0][0]
codec_tag=0x0000
sample_fmt=s16
sample_rate=48000
channels=2
bits_per_sample=0
id=N/A
r_frame_rate=0/0
avg_frame_rate=125/3
time_base=1/1000
start_time=0.000000
duration=N/A
nb_frames=N/A
TAG:language=cze
[/STREAM]
```

Comment: Do you really have a single video stream with multiple resolutions?  That's not a setup that's widely supported by either codecs or playback software.  Can you post the output of `ffprobe -show_streams input_mkv` so that we can get an idea of how FFmpeg sees the file's organization?

Comment: Added the information you requested, and what i've figured out till now.

Answer (score 3):

FFmpeg video filters have a [surprisingly rich set of logical functions](http://ffmpeg.org/ffmpeg.html#Expression-Evaluation) for building complex filters and you should be able to use those to preserve the changing SAR in your file.  Try something like this:

```
ffmpeg ... -vf scale='if(gt(dar\, 4/3)\, 512) + ifnot(gt(dar\, 4/3)\, 384):-1' ...
```

Replacing `512` and `384` with appropriate values as necessary.  That said, I don't have a multi-SAR video to test with, so YMMV.

You might also look into the [`showinfo` filter](http://ffmpeg.org/ffmpeg.html#showinfo) to get excruciatingly detailed information about each frame, and potentially the [`setsar` filter](http://ffmpeg.org/ffmpeg.html#setdar_002c-setsar), though the lack of frame-specific variables would suggest difficulty in changing it midstream.

Comment: Here's a sample: http://db.tt/0AOs4x2f . This didn't work, the video maintains it's constant size. I think the problem is that ffmpeg takes an SAR for the entire video based on the first frame, and simply puts that in the entire remaining video. Is there a way in which I could make it look for the data in each frame?

Comment: [ffmpeg man pages](http://stuff.onse.fi/man?program=ffmpeg&section=1) have fairly complete description of filter expressions.